# How to check, if a php string contains only english letters and digits?

Tags: php, regex

In JS I used this code:

```
if(string.match(/[^A-Za-z0-9]+/))
```

but I don't know, how to do it in PHP.

Answer (score 111, accepted):

Use [preg_match()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match.php).

```
if (!preg_match('/[^A-Za-z0-9]/', $string)) // '/[^a-z\d]/i' should also work.
{
  // string contains only english letters & digits
}
```

Comment: yes. it looks more efficient. To look for the first non-in-range character seems more sensible than scanning whole string.

Comment: N.B english verison of above link here: http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match.php

Comment: I just tried this and the use of the ! operator gives wrong results. The code inside the if statement will be executed if the string does not contain only english letters & digits.

Comment: @chap could you please provide an example of "non working" string ?

Comment: For example if I give the string "{}\" the code inside your if statement will execute. But your comment inside the if statement // string contains only english letters & digits indicates that you want the code inside the if statement to execute only if the string contains a-z A-Z or 0-9, however by using the ! your code does the opposite.

Comment: @chap did you see the ^ char at the beginning of the regex? It means that as soon as an "invalid" char is found, preg_match() returns true. Without the !, the if block would be executed for any "invalid" string. I will retest the whole thing ASAP however & will keep you informed.

Comment: @FrostyZ you are right. I didn't know that the ^ negated the rest of the expression, so I didn't understand why I was getting the result. But now I know it makes perfect sense. Sorry.

Comment: Where is the space included in regex

Answer (score 34):

```
if(ctype_alnum($string)) {
    echo "String contains only letters and numbers.";
}
else {
    echo "String doesn't contain only letters and numbers.";
}
```

Comment: Not sure why people are not voting the ctype function. I can't imaging there is a performance issue with the range of ctype functions.

Comment: ctype_alnum are locale depended so it might not work as you wish !

Answer (score 13):

if you need to check if it is English or not. you could use below function. might help someone..

```
function is_english($str)
{
    if (strlen($str) != strlen(utf8_decode($str))) {
        return false;
    } else {
        return true;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 11):

You can use [preg_match()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match.php) function for example.

```
if (preg_match('/[^A-Za-z0-9]+/', $str))
{
  // ok...
}
```

Answer (score 7):

Have a look at this **shortcut**

```
if(!preg_match('/[^\W_ ] /',$string)) {

}
```

the `class [^\W_]` matches **any letter or digit** but not underscore .  And note the `!` symbol . It will save you from scanning entire user input .

Answer (score 5):

```
if(preg_match('/[^A-Za-z0-9]+/', $str)) {
    // ...
}
```

Answer (score 2):

```
if (preg_match('/^[\w\s?]+$/si', $string)) {
    // input text is just English or Numeric or space
}
```

Comment: It depends on locale. For me (French, locale fr_fr) `\w` matches all characters with diacritic like `éèçàÀ...`

Answer (score 1):

```
if(preg_match('/^[A-Za-z0-9]+$/i', $string)){ // '/^[A-Z-a-z\d]+$/i' should work also
// $string constains both string and integer
}
```

The carrot was in the wrong place so it would have search for everything but what is inside the square brackets. When the carrot is outside it searches for what is in the square brackets.

Answer (score 0):

PHP can compare a string to a regular expression using `preg_match(regex, string)` like this:

```php
if (!preg_match('/[^A-Za-z0-9]+/', $string)) {
    // $string contains only English letters and digits
}
```

Answer (score -1):

The following code will take care about special characters and spaces

```
$string = 'hi, how are you ?';
if (!preg_match('/[^A-Za-z0-9 #$%^&*()+=\-\[\]\';,.\/{}|":<>?~\\\\]+/', $string)) // '/[^a-z\d]/i' should also work.
{
    echo 'english';
}else
{
    echo 'non-english';
}
```