# how to write a regular expression that ONLY accepts strings

Tags: javascript, regex

I am trying to understand regular expressions, i find it really confusing to understand it. I need to know how to write a regular expression that ONLY matches strings, NO NUMBERS, NO SPECIAL CHARACTERS, just letters from A - Z. I have to say that I tried using `\[a-z]\` but it didn't work as i wanted. These are some of the results that I want:

```
pe<.?ter -----> should return false
ale8 ---------> should return false
?ramon -------> should return false
tho<>?mass----> should return false

peter -----> should return true
alex ------> should return true
ramon -----> should return true
thomas ----> should return true
```

Comment: `^[a-zA-Z]+$` that should do it? From beginning to end. Has to be at least one letter

Comment: @Matt—perhaps with an *i* flag.

Comment: Numbers and special characters can be strings, even if there are no letters in the string. So what you're looking for is a regex that only accepts letters.

Comment: Regular expressions are case sensitive, so you'll need to use the `i` flag: `/^[a-z]+$/i`. Or you can test for both uppercase and lowercase explicitly as the other Matt did.

Comment: And you didn't find ANYTHING online ANYWHERE about doing this? Like https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions#Using_parenthesized_substring_matches , http://perldoc.perl.org/perlrequick.html#Matching-repetitions or an interactive tool like http://regexpal.com/ ? You were already so close, how did you run out of patience?

Comment: [StackOverflow solution, but with digits][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9351306/how-to-check-if-a-php-string-contains-only-english-letters-and-digits

- you could delete digits from there

Comment: http://regexpal.com/ is your friend. Test javascript regexes on the fly

Answer (score 5):

This should work for you:

```
 var re = /^[a-z]+$/i;
```

[**See here**](https://regex101.com/r/xR0sZ3/1)

Answer (score 2):

Your regex returns true if it find ONE letter from a to z, only lowercase, in your string.

To make what you want, use `/^[a-zA-Z]+$/` or `/^[a-z]+$/i`.

`^` make that your regex start from the begining of the string.

`[a-zA-Z]` make the regex to find one letter, lowercase OR uppercase (note that you could use instead the i modifier which make the search case insensitive).

`+` make the regex to search for one or more times the previous element.

`$` make sure that your regex end at the end of the string.