# Check if string contains only English alphabets , digits and symbols

Tags: php

I want to check for string that contains only english alphabets , digits and symbols.I tried below code but it works only when all the characters are different language.

```
if(strlen($string) != mb_strlen($string, 'utf-8'))
    { 
 echo "No English words ";
     }
    else {
echo "only english words"; 
   }
```

For example

```
1. hellow hi 123#!@#!@#()#@# -- true
2. ព្រាប សុវ ok yes #@# - false
3. this is good 123 - true
4. ព្រាប -- false
```

p.s : my question is not duplicate because other questions only cover alphabets and symbols , mine covers symbol too

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9351306/how-to-check-if-a-php-string-contains-only-english-letters-and-digits this should be your case

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to check, if a php string contains only english letters and digits?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9351306/how-to-check-if-a-php-string-contains-only-english-letters-and-digits)

Comment: @IvanFranchi and kris : it does not cover symbols

Comment: Depending on the text encoding, you can use `[\x00-\x7f]` or `[\u0000-\u007f]`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Would determining if a string is just printable ASCII work? If so you can use this regex:

```
[ -~]
```

http://www.catonmat.net/blog/my-favorite-regex/

If you need non ASCII characters as well than you can use the Wikipedia page to get the specific unicode formats that you need:

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Unicode_characters#Control_codes

Comment: $ok = preg_match('/[ -~]/', "ព្រាប សុវ ok yes");
echo $ok; it returns 1 for this too

Comment: @Vishnu In this case, you need to anchor the regular expression. Try `preg_match('/^[ -~]*$/', $text);`.