# Prepared statement for adding tables to MySQL (PHP)

Tags: php, mysql

This code works and adds tables to my database. My question is how do I protect it with prepared statements.

```
 require "conn.php";
    $MyServer =($_POST["username"]);
        $sql = ("CREATE TABLE $MyServer (
            id INT(6) UNSIGNED AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY, 
            username VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL
            )");
        if($conn->query($sql) === TRUE){
            echo "Table created successfully";
        }
```

I am using MySQLi.
I tryed this and it isn't adding the table.

```
$MyServer =($_POST["username"]);
    if (!preg_match('^/[A-Za-z][A-Za-z0-9]{0,7}$/', $MyServer)) {
       throw new Exception ('username unsuitable for use as a table name');
    }
    $sql = ("CREATE TABLE `$MyServer` (
        id INT(6) UNSIGNED AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY, 
        username VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL
        )");
    if($conn->query($sql) === TRUE){
        echo "Table created successfully";
    } else {
        echo "Table is not created successfully ";
    }
```

Comment: protect what ? what you wanna protect ?you mean how you can avoid sql injections and all

Comment: You are allowing users to create tables based on a `$POST` variable?  Probably not the best plan.  You'll want to sanitize / clean up the table name at least.

Comment: I want to protect it from injections

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Can PHP PDO Statements accept the table or column name as parameter?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/182287/can-php-pdo-statements-accept-the-table-or-column-name-as-parameter)

Comment: That's not me. I am using MySQLi

Comment: @EgorCherkashin is the username already in another database table?

Comment: why would you want to allow users to create tables in the database? Sounds like bad planning to me ~ what if `$_POST['username']='fred; drop database;';`?

Comment: @MinistryOfChamps yes, i do.

Comment: @RamRaider I need a lot of info per user.

Comment: I still cannot understand why you would think that having multiple tables ( per user ) is better than a correctly structured database schema

Comment: I want users to be able to save other users username and I need to be able to go through each of those users.

Comment: Any Ideas for doing it differently?

Comment: Allowing people to create tables like that is a **horrible** idea. Even if there's a lot of information per user, they should all be stored in tables you create. That is much more secure, clean and structured. How much data is needed per user?

Comment: @EgorCherkashin The only way the selected answer will really work is if your usernames only have alphabetic and numeral characters only. Make sure that is the case with your usernames.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess you're thinking about how to avoid SQL injection into your query via that `$MyServer` variable in your sample program.

You cannot use a parameterized value to name a table (or a database, or a column) in SQL. You must do the variable substitution shown in your program.

You can use php to sanitize your `$MyServer` variable before you use it for subsitution though.

For example:   [How to check, if a php string contains only english letters and digits?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9351306/how-to-check-if-a-php-string-contains-only-english-letters-and-digits)

You could do this, or something like it. This requires the variable to start with a letter, then contain up to seven more characters that are letters or digits. If the variable doesn't match it throws an exception.

```
if (!preg_match('^/[A-Za-z][A-Za-z0-9]{0,7}$/', $MyServer)) {
     throw new Exception ('username unsuitable for use as a table name');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Although it is questionable whether it is a good plan to allow users to create tables, to answer your question:

First of all, make sure your variable doesn't contain any strange character. Although MySQL [allows (a subset of) unicode characters](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/identifiers.html), you probably only want normal letters and numbers:

```
if (
    !preg_match('/^[a-z0-9]+$/i', $MyServer)
    || preg_match(/^[0-9]+$/, $MyServer) // Identifiers may begin with a digit but unless quoted may not consist solely of digits.
    || strlen($MyServer) > 64 // Limit of table-name length
) {
    // Insert your own error handling
    die('Not allowed');
}
```

Second, to make sure SQL treat it as a identifier, quote it in backticks

```
$sql = "CREATE TABLE `$MyServer` (...etc..."
```

`CREATE TABLE index (...etc...` will raise an error in MySQL because `index` is a keyword

```
CREATE TABLE `index` (...etc...
```

wont, because it is marked as an identifier.

Answer (score 0):

Honestly, you are really opening yourself up to SQL injection here by getting the data from `$_POST`.

Your method is a definite no go unless your usernames are already stored in your database and do not have special characters that will lead to SQL injection (such as quotations).

EDIT: I see two answers above that compliment what I have said, you could use one of those two answers (O. Jones is my preferred one).

If you want your code to be a bit more in line with PDO procedure (binding PDO values to avoid SQL injection), why not create one table with columns (username, saved_username) and you can interact with the information in that table effectively with PDO statements.

For example, all you will have to do to insert data would be:

```
$query = 'INSERT INTO table (username, saved_username) VALUES (:username, :username_to_save)';
$stmt->bindParam(':username', $_POST['username']);
$stmt->bindParam(':username_to_save', $_POST['username_to_save']);
$stmt->execute()
```

And to select the data:

```
$query = 'SELECT * FROM table WHERE username = :username';
$stmt->bindParam(':username', $_POST['username']);
$stmt->execute()
$users_saved_usernames = $stmt->fetchAll();
```